# "My room is moldy" am I describing "its smell or appearance"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

If I say:

> - My room is moldy.

It can simultaneously give two descriptions

-its appearance and smell

How could I know, or be more specific about either its appearance or smell is meant to be presented in the sentence.

[image: moldy room]

Comment: Could you edit to correct your spelling of the word "I", it is alway written with a capital.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If someone said to me as a native speaker that their room is mouldy, I would expect this to mean that they had *seen* mould on the walls. Of course, with visible mould also comes the smell, so that's implied.

You can be more direct with your verbs if you want to talk about the appearance or smell:

> My room **looks** mouldy.

or

> My room **smells** mouldy.

You could also choose to be more direct about what is mouldy, or how you know there is mould.

> There is mould on the room's walls.

or

> I've found mould behind a cupboard.